# Preserving distinct values VBA excel - deleting all the rest

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a column with random values that has repeats data in a certain format:

Column 1

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
A
A
D
D
E
F
F
F
G
...
```

I tried using

```
 Dim i As Integer
    Dim noRows As Integer


'count rows
noRows = Range("B2:B10000").Rows.Count

'delete row entries that are duplicates..
For i = 1 To noRows
    If Range("H2").Cells(i + 1, 1) = Range("H2").Cells(i, 1) Then
    Range("H2").Cells(i + 1).Resize(1, 2).Clear
    End If
Next i
```

Which I quickly realised would not work at all.

how could I write a code so the output would be:

Column 1

```
A 
[..]
[..]
[..] 
B 
[..] 
C 
[..] 
[..] 
[..] 
A 
D 
[..] 
[..] 
E 
F 
[..] 
[..] 
G 
...
```

Where the [..]s are nulls or zero

Disregard the second "66.63" field which is green, it should be red

[image: Disregard the second "66.63" field which is green, it should be red]

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631231/remove-duplicates-from-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific. 

Essentially, I want to retain values as long as they are not the same as the immediately previous one, and they should retain their place too..


So: A A B B B C C A A A D D D

Becomes

A [...] B [...] [...] C [...] A [...] [...] D [...] [...]

Quite different from the linked thread where duplicates are removed entirely.

Comment: Hi, will the duplicates always be directly next to each other like in your example? If so Jules answer can be adapted to work very easily with any length, otherwise you may need some different code.

Comment: @JoshWhitfield I've added an image showing what the data set looks like - probably should have done that to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the previous value in a variable and compare it against the cell's value.

```
Dim sPrv
Dim oRng
Dim i

sPrv = "" '<- previous value
Set oRng = ActiveSheet.Range("H2", ActiveSheet.Range("H2").End(xlDown)) '<- set range of one column starting from H2 to the end of row

Debug.Print oRng.Rows.Count '<- Row count.

For i = 1 To oRng.Rows.Count

    Debug.Print i, sPrv, oRng.Cells(i,1), sPrv = oRng.Cells(i,1) '<- print counter, previous value, cell value, sPrv = Cell ?

    If sPrv = oRng.Cells(i, 1) Then '<- current value the same as previous
        oRng.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" '<- Set the cell value to blank
    Else
        sPrv = oRng.Cells(i, 1).Value '<- Keep the new value for the next comparison and leave the cell value as is
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Some reason this is not working.

My H column range is from H2:H450, so I input:


`Sub trial_1()

    Dim sprv
    Dim orng
    Dim i
    
    sprv = "" '<previous value
    Set orng = Range("H2:H500")
    
    For i = 1 To orn.Rows.Count
     If sprv = orng.Cells(i, 1) Then '<- current value the same as previous
        orng.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" '<- Set the cell value to blank
    Else
        sprv = orng.Cells(i, 1).Value '<- Keep the new value for the next comparison and leave the cell value as is
    End If
Next
End Sub`

I have attached an image to give a visualisation

Comment: What is the result after you run the script?  Are the values exactly the same (no rounding)?

Comment: Yes, it remains the exact same

Comment: I've added debugging lines on the code try that and see what are the values.

Comment: Thanks @jules, it still doesn't change anything, however.

Comment: What are the output from debug.print? Do you know how to read the debug result on immediate window?  On the visual basic IDE, press ctrl-G to display immediate window .

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used that function before; This was the output:

http://i.imgur.com/S2LmGv1.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102300/discussion-between-jules-and-elbarto).

Comment: you saved my life, thank you Jules. Award this young man money/prizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work. I have created a fake column which will flag as 1 in that column just to identify the repeat.

Code:

```
Sub stack()

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To s1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

  If s1.Cells(i, 1).Value = s1.Cells(i - 1, 1) _
       Then
        s1.Cells(i, 2).Value = "1"
    End If
Next

For j = 2 To s1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    If s1.Cells(j, 2).Value = 1 Then
        s1.Cells(j, 1).Value = "[..]"

    End If
Next

s1.Columns("B").Delete

End Sub
```