# Hi, How to remove duplicate values from specific column using Macro

Tags: vba, macros

Below mentioned code is nor working, is there anything to be modified?

```
Sub duplicate()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$65535").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=15, Header:= _
    xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631231/remove-duplicates-from-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba

Comment: @ShaiRado, Thanks but that code is not working. I have 20 columns in my sheet and i want to remove duplicates in column 15.

Comment: you can also reply to the answer I gave you on your previous question

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your data?

Answer (score 0):

paste below code in vba

Sub duplicate()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$65535").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=15, Header:=xlNo

End Sub

Comment: You really didn't need to post three separate answers for all of this.