# Error: invalid or unqualified - VBA copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy a column of data from one sheet into an empty sheet containing only the matching "tickers" for a large list...once this is done I'm looking to delete all duplicates or do not copy them at all.

**A)** Could someone help figure out why I'm getting an error when setting the "Ticker"

**B)** What would the most efficient method be for removing the duplicates?

```
Dim BottomRow As Long
Dim TopRow As Long
Dim col As Integer
Dim Ticker As String
Dim RngY As Range

TopRow = 6

For col = 4 To 3 + (2 * 26) Step 2

Ticker = .Cell(TopRow - 1, col - 3).Value
BottomRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
.Range(.Cells(TopRow, col), .Cells(BottomRow, col)).Copy

Worksheets("TSX-CleanDate").Activate
RngY = Worksheets("Source").Range("3A:3XFD").Find(Ticker, lookat:=xlPart)

.Cells(4, RngY).Paste

Next
```

Comment: There is no worksheet reference to qualift the `.` in `.cells` or `.range`

Comment: You are using `.Cell` and `.Range`, but, as far as I can  it is not referring to anything since your are not using `With... End With` See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) for details

Comment: Are you missing the `With` block somewhere in the posted code?

Comment: Also the first `.Cell` should be `.cells`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error when setting `Ticker` is because you are not referencing any worksheet in your code.

```
Ticker = .Cell(TopRow - 1, col - 3).Value
```

That `.Cell` part would only work if your code was in a `With` block, but since it's not, you need to fully qualify the worksheet like so (also, you should be using `Cells` instead of `Cell`):

```
Ticker = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(TopRow - 1, col - 3).Value
```

As for part B, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631821/1148564).

Comment: You are repeating the original `cell` vs `cells` made in the original (mentioned in comments above by @Brotato)

Comment: @Jeeped I realized that after I posted the answer. We were all within a minute of each other :)